# Making a bottomleftcorner triangle in Haskell with IO()

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand why my code doesn't work:

```
writeRow :: Int -> IO()
writeRow x = putStr(concat (replicate x "* "))

triangle :: Int -> IO()
triangle x = do
       writeRow x
       putStr ""
       triangle x-1
```

My thinking is, that writeRow creates a row of x times " * ", so if x = 4, triangle 4 will write

```
 * * * *
```

As triangle is called recursivly with x -1, the next line will be:

```
 * * *
```

And so on ... until:

```
 * * * *
 * * *
 * *
 *
```

But it just outputs it all on one line:

```
* * * * * * * *
```

What seems to be the issue? :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`putStr` only prints the string, it does *not* write a new line, you should use `putStrLn`. Furthermore you should use `triangle (x-1)` so with parenthesis around the `x-1` part, and specify a base case for the recursion with the triangle:

```
writeRow :: Int -> IO()
writeRow x = putStr(concat (replicate x "* "))

triangle :: Int -> IO()
triangle x | x <= 0 = pure ()
triangle x = do
    writeRow x
    putStrLn ""
    triangle (x-1)
```

With these modifications, we obtain:

```
Prelude> triangle 4
* * * * 
* * * 
* * 
*
```